# Batch File run npm start

Tags: angular, batch-file, npm

I have an angular application, that can be started with the command `npm start` in the console. Now I want to create a batchfile, that executes "npm install" when started. This is the batch file I created:

frontend.bat

```
cd "<path>"
npm start
```

When I execute the File, the console shows up quickly, but then nothing happens.

My question is, is it even possible to do npm start in a batch file? And if not, is there another way to start a angular application with a batch file?

Thank you

Comment: I'm going to assume that `npm` is really `npm.cmd` or `npm.bat`, so you should use `Call`, i.e. `call npm…` or use it's extension so as not to get confused, `call npm.cmd…`. When the script returns from the `Call`, the next line of your script will run, if you don't have one, you should include a `Timeout` or `Pause` to give you sufficient time to read anything before the window closes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could try to pause the execution of the batch file with

```
cd "<path>"
npm start
pause
```

otherwise the batch file will exit and take npm down with it.

Comment: You need to use `call npm start` since `npm` is a batch file on its own; otherwise `pause` is never going to be executed...

Comment: The "pause" command doesn't work for me as I run "npm run start" and pass parameters.

Answer (score 2):

NPM does an EXIT. You can do this (modify as desired).

`CMD /C "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm" i --loglevel error`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is writing `cmd /k` at the end of the file. It is better than `pause`, because with `pause` terminal window will be closed anyway once any key is pressed. `cmd /k` will leave the window open and ready for input. To maintain clean terminal you can add `@echo off` before it, so the `cmd /k` does not get printed.

```
cd "<path>"
npm start
@echo off
cmd /k
```