# How to enable one click button to run Fastapi and React app?

Tags: reactjs, fastapi

I'm new in working with React js and fastapi.
for fastapi we need to use three comamands (cd / \venv\Scripts\activate / uvicorn main:app --reload
)
for react (cd /npm start)
My boss ask me if there is a way to lunch the whole app with one click
as I searched I couldn't find a way except deploying the app on remote server?
Is there another way?

Comment: React is frontend. FastAPI is backend. You can't "launch" both of them at the same time, because one is "launched" by the dev team and the other is "launched" by the end user. Edit: I misunderstood. You probably want to use them both in development. In that case it depends on what OS you are using. It's probably possible to create some bash or .bat file to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I made a .bat file for react, Do I need to make a separate one for fastapi? @EmilKarlsson

Comment: If you are using both React and FastAPI on your local machine, you should be able to start both with the same .bat file.

Comment: `cd web_app 
npm start

cd api 
call .\venv\Scripts\activate.bat 
cd app 
uvicorn main:app --reload`

Comment: Here is my commands, I tried to put them in one .bat file but it didn't work, I used separate files for frontend and backend

Comment: There are some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56542233/12057512